# Call Higher Order function of Kotlin from Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, higher-order-functions, kotlin-function-type

**Kotin Class**

```
class LoginService{

    fun getLoginData(loginData: String) {
        request(LoginApi.create().getLoginData(loginData))}
    }

    fun changePassword(_:String){
        request(LoginApi.create().changePassword(_)
    }

    class RequestData {
        var retrofitCall: ((String) -> Unit)? = null
    }
}
```

**Java Class**

```
class LoginModel{

    private void loginData(){
        RequestData data = new RequestData();
        requestData.setRetrofitCall(username ->LoginService::getLoginData)
    }

    private void changePassword(){
        RequestData data = new RequestData();
        requestData.setRetrofitCall(username ->LoginService::changePassword)
     }
 }
```

**requestData.setRetrofitCall(username ->LoginService::changePassword)**

**Why Higher order function** :

Since i have to differentiate between each API call for calling a function from its feature hence trying to use.

How to call the above highlighted code?

Comment: That's incorrect use of lambda. `username ->` means "this is a new function", which means you can't pass a function reference there. Just use `setRetrofitCall(LoginService::changePassword)`

Comment: Do i need to upgrade to Java 1.8 to do that?

Comment: You need Java 1.8 to use Java lambdas, yes.

Comment: I dont want to do that,is there any other way?

Comment: You can use retrolambda. But you can upgrade to Java 8 without any noticeable loss in platforms. The Java 8 base language features are available on all platforms.

Comment: You can alternatively use anonymous classes

Comment: @Pavitra Could you please answer above question with anonymous class.

Comment: @SachinKasaraddi I could write, but just follow the steps given in this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/from-anonymous-class-to-single-line-lambda-in-3-st) in reverse order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Kotlin Functional Interfaces in Java is a little tricky and not very clean.

Your `setRetrofitCall()` would need to look something like this:

```
setRetrofitCall(new Function1<String, Unit>() {
        @Override
        public Unit invoke(String s) {
            LoginService.getLoginData(s); //I'm pretty sure LoginService is supposed to be static?
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: You don't need to refer to `Function1` (which I find quite ugly to do so even in Kotlin). See the other two answers.

Answer (score 5):

More short code with Lamda expression

```
setRetrofitCall(s -> {
        LoginService.getLoginData(s); 
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a named class and don't want to refer to Kotlin's interfaces, you can use `::`.

```java
class CallbackHandler {
  Unit invoke(String s) {
    LoginService.getLoginData(s);
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
  }
}

CallbackHandler handler = new CallbackHandler();
setRetrofitCall(handler::invoke);
```

Otherwise for anonymous class you can use lambda expression per chakrapani's answer.

```java
setRetrofitCall(s -> {
  LoginService.getLoginData(s); 
  return Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```